# Extract substring from string in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to extract a text that is surrounded by `***[some text]` strings, like in the following example:

```
some text
some text
***[some text]
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
***[some text]
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
***[some text]
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED TOO
***[some text]
some text
```

the output should be:

```
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED TOO
```

I tried `PATINDEX` like here, but couln't find the way to extract the string.

```
PATINDEX('%[*][*][*][[]%]%%[*][*][*][[]%]%',@Text)
```

I am looking forward to hearing any suggestions.

Comment: Does the text you show represent a field, a row or a row set?

Comment: @Cos Callis It represents one `NVARCHAR` field

Comment: Got a CR LF on the end of those lines?

Comment: @DKnight theres `char(10)` character, but any example working for single-line text is welcome

Comment: And the start section delimiter is really exactly the same as the end section delimiter?

Comment: @Martin Yes it may be, but any example for different delimiters like `***[some text1]` - `***[some text2]` is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a regex solution and I'm still a SQL novice so may not be optimal but you should be able to parse with a `WHILE` loop using

`CHARINDEX` for the `***` then using that as a starting point to
`CHARINDEX` to the `LF` Use that as the starting point for a
`SUBSTRING` with the ending point being a `CHARINDEX` of the next `***`
concatenate the Substring to your output, move past the ending `***` and loop to find the next one.

I'll play with it some and see if I can add an example.
**EDIT - This probably needs more error checking**

```
declare @inText nvarchar(2000) = 'some text 
some text 
***[some text] 
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED 
***[some text] 
some text 
some text 
some text 
some text 
some text 
***[some text] 
THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED TOO 
***[some text] 
some text '

declare @delim1 nvarchar(50) = '***'
declare @delim2 char = char(10)
declare @output nvarchar(1000) = ''
declare @position int
declare @positionEnd int

set @position = CHARINDEX(@delim1,@inText)
while (@position != 0 and @position is not null)
BEGIN
  set @position = CHARINDEX(@delim2,@inText,@position)
  set @positionEnd = CHARINDEX(@delim1,@inText,@position)
  set @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@inText,@position,@positionEnd-@position)
  set @position = CHARINDEX(@delim1,@inText,@positionEnd+LEN(@delim1))
END
select @output
```

Comment: I think you could [probably use this as a base](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/pattern-based-split-string.aspx) then call the UDF using `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Martin - oooo more reading material - thanks for the feedback it is very much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

For the somewhat easier case raised in the comments you could do

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
 SELECT '
    some text
    some text
    ***[some text 1]
    THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
    ***[some text 2]
    some text
    some text
    some text
    some text
    some text
    ***[some text 1]
    THIS SHOULD BE EXTRACTED TOO
    ***[some text 2]
    some text'
)
SELECT col.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<a keep="false">' + 
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(C,'***[some text 2]','</a><a keep="false">'),
                        '***[some text 1]','</a><a keep="true">') + 
                    '</a>' AS xml) as xcol) x
CROSS APPLY xcol.nodes('/a[@keep="true"]') tab(col)
```

Comment: I tested your solution vs my which is above. It takes 98% of batch. My just only 2%. I think it is because of XML.

Comment: Yes the `XML` reader functions definitely don't have great performance. Additionally my answer would need some more `REPLACE` operations in there if the text might contain characters such as `<` in order to replace them with the corresponding XML entities.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but I don't think there's a clean way to do this directly in SQL. I would use a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) and use regular expressions from C# or your .NET language of choice.

See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2005/06/29/working-with-regular-expressions/) (or [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)) for a relevant example using regexes.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use C# or CLR stored procedures, I can perform only select statements...

Comment: The link of the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx is broken :(

Comment: @RobertLujo I found another example here at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2005/06/29/working-with-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 2):

You can find this in my blog:
http://sql-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/04/extract-strings-with-delimiters.html
It is pure solution with no additional modification, only delimiters sequences should be decalred.

Comment: Thanks your solution is nice but i get `Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function` when I try to change delimiters to meet my needs. Also it is a bit slow or my server is slow, I am not sure.

Comment: Please write your delimiters. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the xp_regex_match as described in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/xpregex.aspx?q=use+sql+function+to+parse+text to parse your nvarchar field. I wrote something similar quite a while back.